# Why does my electron app display the source code in the browser window?

Tags: electron

I made an electron app, and when it opens, it shows the actual contents of the php file (it's not just php, there's html of course). I was wondering how I can get it to display the html in the browser window and not just the source code of it.

Edit: I just fixed it by making it an html file and not a php file, but is there any way to make the electron app execute php code?

Comment: Is your browser able to render php code or is it rather showing the html, generated by your server using your php code? I think your problem may lie in trying to make the chromium understand php directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Short. No.

Php needs a php interpreter which is part of a large number of web servers, whereas Electron is using Node.js - a server side JavaScript environment. So there is no way I know of you can execute php in Electron. (Beside bundling a complete web server like Apache inside your Application, but that would take a lot of effort)

Comment: Thank you so much, I just found out that you can encrypt strings in javascript though by using crypto.js, that's what I needed the PHP for. Have a great day!